# Google Sheets/Excel: Is there a way to pull information from different columns depending on the value of another column?

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a summary of data (responses) in a separate sheet that pulls a value from a calculated column based on the value in another column.

For example, my data output has *Item Type* in column C and columns D:L are item descriptions based on type.  Every row (response) has an item type in column C (e.g., office supplies), then depending on that item type there is a description (e.g., pens) in the appropriate column (e.g., *Office supplies item description*).  All other description cells in that row are blank.

What I want is to summarize the data from D:L into one column (e.g., *Item description*).  In other words, I want to summarize all of the non-blank cells in D:L in one column.

I must add: I'm using Google Sheets with the data output from a Google Form.  Every time a new response is added to the sheet, a new row is inserted below the previous row, so using reference cells (e.g., C2) doesn't seem to work.

My first time posting here so please let me know if I need to provide more information.

Example:

Response data
[image]

End goal/summary

[image]

Comment: A screenshot would be equal to 1000 words.

Comment: Ok, I've added a couple screenshots.

Comment: Maybe TEXTJOIN would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks! That might actually be the easiest way to do it... Just got to work around the row insertion (makes it hard to reference cells).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was able to do is create a FILTER of the Google Forms output in a separate sheet (which created a copy of the responses that would NOT insert a new row for each entry), then use TEXTJOIN (referencing columns D:L in the new sheet) to get the info in one column on the summary sheet.

Thank you to BigBen for reminding me in the comments of the TEXTJOIN function :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below macro to achieve this result :

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
Sheets("Response Data").Select
    Range("C1").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    LR = ActiveCell.Row
    
    Sheets("Summary").Select
    
    Range("B2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete
    
    Range("B2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=INDEX('Response Data'!R1C4:R" & LR & "C12,ROW(Summary!RC[-1]),MATCH(Summary!RC[-1] & "" item description"",'Response Data'!R1C4:R1C12,0))"
    
    Range("A2").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Range("B2", "B" & ActiveCell.Row).Select
    Selection.FillDown
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! I am hoping to find something without macros but will try this if formulas won't work.  (Can you use macros on Google Sheets?)